# How to use a table variable in an "update from select" query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, table-variable

I have this table variable declaration followed by a query:

```
DECLARE @CurrentItems TABLE
(
    ItemId uniqueidentifier,
    ItemUnits int
)

UPDATE U SET U.Units = U.Units + [@CurrentItems].ItemUnits
    FROM @CurrentItems CI INNER JOIN U ON U.UId=CI.ItemId;
```

And `U` is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[U] (
    [UId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [Units]       INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL
);
```

When I run that in SQL Management Studio against SQL Server 2005 Express I get the following:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>
> Invalid object name '@CurrentItems'.

I've already looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1499172/57428) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4252394/57428) very similar questions but can't figure out how to solve the problem.

What's the actual problem and how do I resolve that?

Comment: `UPDATE U SET U.Units = U.Units + CI.ItemUnits FROM @CurrentItems CI INNER JOIN U ON U.UId=CI.ItemId;` works, I have tried right now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've aliased `@CurrentItems` with `CI` so just use `CI`:

```
UPDATE U SET U.Units = U.Units + CI.ItemUnits
    FROM @CurrentItems CI INNER JOIN U ON U.UId=CI.ItemId;
```

Also take a look at your query you have something like `U.UId = CU.ItemID`. What is CU? You've made an alias for @CurrentItems with CI, so what is the purpose of CU?  If this is a mistake, just a typo make sure you change any reference to `CU` with `CI`.

You also don't tell us what `U` is, I hope this is a valid table.

Comment: @sharptooth and you removed `CU` completly?

Comment: Unfortunately I used your table definitions and am not able to reproduce this, it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: My fault - I forgot to drop the `[]` from the table variable name. Works without `[]`.

Comment: @Sharptooth are you running this in the correct database context?  You should use the `USE` keyword and specify the database you are working on. `Use MyDB...`

Comment: @sharptooth - you should of copy pasted my code :) you don't need `[]` in the table variable as it is aliased.