# Where's the bug in this simple UPDATE FROM query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This should be very simple, but I want to get this right because I'm making a change to a live database (it is backed up).

I imported a few column values from CSV file to a database table.

Now I just want to update a target table (T in query) from the imported source table (S in the query).

I get the error:  `The multi-part identifier "T.account_manager_id" could not be bound.`

```
update DADatabaseMarch2012.dbo.Campaign

set 
    T.[account_manager_id]=S.[account_manager_id]
   ,T.[campaign_status_id]=S.[campaign_status_id]
   ,T.[ad_manager_id]=S.[ad_manager_id]
   ,T.[advertiser_id]=S.[advertiser_id]
from 
    [zMarch12CampaignsRestore].[dbo].[March12Eom_Campaigns] S
    inner join DADatabaseMarch2012.dbo.Campaign T ON S.id = T.id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a table variable in an "update from select" query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535362/how-to-use-a-table-variable-in-an-update-from-select-query)

Comment: Not the same query but the same type of issue.  Use the alias name in the update statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it this way, using the alias name as the target of the UPDATE.

```
update T

set 
    [account_manager_id]=S.[account_manager_id]
   ,[campaign_status_id]=S.[campaign_status_id]
   ,[ad_manager_id]=S.[ad_manager_id]
   ,[advertiser_id]=S.[advertiser_id]
from 
    [zMarch12CampaignsRestore].[dbo].[March12Eom_Campaigns] S
    inner join DADatabaseMarch2012.dbo.Campaign T ON S.id = T.id
```

Comment: Does this really work? I think the update clause needs to reference exactly the same table as the from clause. See my answer.

Comment: @usr yes it works.  If you alias a table in an `UPDATE` you must specify the **alias** as the target

Comment: I know but you don't use that table in the from. You use it in a join. Surprising that this is working.

Comment: no, I do use the table that T is an alias for in the join.... maybe one of us is confused (i mean that in an 'it could be me' way)?

Comment: @usr it's an inner join so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4):

Since T is the target table, you don't have to alias it in the left hand side of the assignments (the SETs).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You need to reference the same table in your update as in you from clause. Write "update T".